# Extractors for Centerlock rotors and Shimano HG cassette

Tags: maintenance, disc-brake, tools, hyperglide

I need to buy some basic tools to do some maintenance on my wheels, but I'm confused about what I need.

I want to perform the following operations:

- change the cassette

  - I have a 11-34 10-speed Shimano cassette, CS-M771-10
    [image]
- move the front-wheel diskbrake rotor to another wheel

  - it is the stock rotor that came with the bike, a 160/160mm RT54 rotor
    [image: Rotor detail]

It's not clear to me what tools I need to work on these components, specifically what lockring tools I need to remove and then install the components (I mean besides a wrench and a chain whip).

Looking at the parts and searching online I came to the conclusion I need a lockring tool like Shimano TL-LR10 for *both* operations, but this struck me as surprising, because I expected Centerlock to require something different)

Can somebody confirm, or direct me to the correct solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a normal Shimano nut tool for HG casettes. It works for both. It is not surprising, the centrelock was specifically designed to use the same tool.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir!

Comment: @larsen and if you end up with the external centrelock lockring...you use a Shimano bottom bracket tool (for original hollowtech II). Easy!